# Memory leak using UIColor

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, uicolor

I'm getting a memory leak in Instruments for the object UIDeviceRGBColor in this line:

```
[[self navigationController] navigationBar].tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:90.0/255.0 green:48.0/255.0 blue:48.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

any suggestions how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try creating a UIColor instance like this

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:90.0/255.0 green:48.0/255.0 blue:48.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

then set the navigation bar tint color

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = color;
```

then release the color object

```
[color release];
```

After that check in Instruments if the object is still leaking.

Comment: If it is still leaking after following the method I suggested above, then @dorianj is probably right and it is just being cached by UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

`colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` produces an auto-released `UIColor`. That should not be the memory leak. I assume that the property setter is also synthesized properly, as it is an Apple class. So I don't see a leak.

Comment: Any idea why Instruments keep spotting this line as a leaking object?

Comment: No, sorry. It looks fine to me. But I may be wrong and Instruments may be right.

Answer (score 1):

There's no leak in your code. If there's any leak at all, it would be in Apple's code (which you can't do anything about aside from filing a bug), but it's far more likely that Instruments is just reporting a false positive.

Answer (score -3):

I would set your tint color like this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:90.0/255.0 green:48.0/255.0 blue:48.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: It may seem the same but you must know that using setters is a different story than using _=_ so it was worth it.

Comment: While stylistically this response might be better, it in no way addresses the possibility of a memory leak (which there is not).